# Counting a digit from second input

Tags: java, loops

If the user enter a first number (ex. 2) and then enter a second number (ex. 124218) then the the code will print how many two's are there in the second input.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = in.nextInt();
int num2 = in.nextInt();
int ans = 0;

while(num2 > 0){
int digit = num2 % 10;

if(digit == num){
ans++;
}
num2 /= 10;
}

System.out.println(ans);
```

but still doesn't count.

*Input: 2 124218*
*Expected output: 2*

**EDIT:** Nevermind i got it. just need to add some variable.

Comment: Why don't you do some basic debugging here? Print out the `num` and `num2` values as you iterate through the loop. Are the values what you expect at each point? If not, why not?

Comment: read the API Scanner then you could find the answer for yourself. The input of 2 (+ENTER) gives num = 2 then  the nextInt() gets the 0 because NEWLINE string is read, not the 2nd input 124218

Answer (score 1):

you need to separate the reminder operation from division, because in reminder you are taking the last digit of number and checking it with `num` input, so you need to do it in other variable:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = in.nextInt();
int num2 = in.nextInt();
int last_digit = 0;

while (num2 > 0) {
    last_digit = num2 % 10;

    if (last_digit == num) {
        num++;
    }
    num2 /= 10;
}

System.out.println(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this code

````
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw3{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum=0;
int num3;
int num = in.nextInt();
int num2 = in.nextInt();

while(num2 > 0){
num3 =num2 % 10;

if(num3 == num){
sum +=1;
}
num2 /= 10;
}

System.out.println(sum);
}} ```
````